# Implementing access rights and security in winforms/wpf

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, implementation

Before I implement access rights and security for an application by copying the implementation of roles in windows and on user creation, each user must be assigned a role to limit his rights (note that i store data on a database which is i dont know if good or not). I don't know if this is how windows do it. So I want to ask how this is done professionally and securely in .NET. Any diagrams of process flow will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds fine, that is what most system I work on do in one form or another. Using Windows users you can be as sure as you can be it is indeed the user logged on to Windows. (Still not 100% though, someone else could logon as guest use a tool to modify the memory where the user name is stored in your app to impersonate them).

How safe is it? Well only as safe as the weakest link: how safe is the data in your database, how safe is the information travelling over the network, how safe is physical access?

What you do not specify is how you control access to the data, one measure you can take to make it *safer* is control access back-end rather than at the application level. e.g. Rather then downloading all data then limiting it bassed on the current user, pass the current user info to the back-end an only return the data they are allowed to see, that way they cannot circumvent your application level security e.g. by eavesdropping the network or modifying the application at runtime (e.g. for WPF see Snoop) or modifying actual binary - for which one technique of mitigating is using signing...

Comment: 1.) how you control access to the data.  Just like you said I download all his rights and control the form based from it.  2.) by pass the current user info to the back-end and only return the data they are allowed to see, you mean the logged in user to the system already has defined access rights for his account, but how are those

Comment: rights saved for that particular user? can you give me an idea. sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: I was assuming the user has the roles he belongs to saved in the back-end so if you pass the user identification to the back-end, you can see the roles they have and return the appropriate data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I understand and to me it seems correct. I am still waiting for other opinions and if nobody has a better answer than yours. I will mark this as the answer. Cheers!